# PyEDA Binary Decision Diagram plotting in IPython

Tags: python-3.x, graphviz, pyeda

After installing Graphviz and gvmagic, I run the following command in order to display the BDD:

```
ff = a|b&c
%dotobj ff
```

However, I get the following error:
FileNotFoundError                         [WinError 2] Le fichier spécifié est introuvable

Any clues please about the reasons behind this error?

Comment: Can you run dot outside of IPython? Just try in a command window `dot -v`

Comment: In Anaconda, it works fine. However, not that successful on a Win Cmd prompt

Comment: I don't know Anaconda, but is this a plain terminal window? and is WinEdt started from within Anaconda?

Comment: Not sure I got your point. It didn't work in a Windows Command prompt although I added the dot.py to the PATH variable

Comment: That is what I got, and my question was directly directed to this to see if the dot.exe can be started from the command prompt (i.e. that dot.exe can be found through the PATH.

Comment: I'm not talking about dot.py but about dot.exe (the excutable from graphviz)! i.e. going back to the basics, the executable that does the work.